# "com.jacob.com.ComFailException: Can't find moniker" Why?

Tags: java, com, jacob

I use jacob last version and jacobgen.

I put all need dll in `c:\windows\system32`

I generated wrapper about dll by jacobgen.

But I got an exception. Google didn't help. :(

```
com.jacob.com.ComFailException: Can't find moniker
```

May be need registy dlls in windows registry?

Comment: My dll don't use sap and di api. :(

Answer (score 2):

COM objects have to be registered to be found. It does not matter in which folder they reside.

Call

```
regsvr32 mycomdll.dll
```

on the dll.