# htmlunit Active Load exception

Tags: java, htmlunit, jacob

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws
FailingHttpStatusCodeException, MalformedURLException,IOException,
InterruptedException {

    final ActiveXComponent activeXComponent = new ActiveXComponent("CLSID:0CA54D3F-CEAE-48AF-9A2B-31909CB9515D");

    WebClient webClient = new WebClient(BrowserVersion.INTERNET_EXPLORER);
    webClient.getOptions().setThrowExceptionOnScriptError(false);
    webClient.getOptions().setActiveXNative(true);
    // https://pbsz.ebank.cmbchina.com/CmbBank_GenShell/UI/GenShellPC/Login/Login.aspx
    HtmlPage page = webClient.getPage("https://pbsz.ebank.cmbchina.com/CmbBank_GenShell/UI/GenShellPC/Login/LoginOLD.aspx");
    System.out.println(page.asXml()); }
```

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BR4xr.png)

> Exception in thread "main" com.jacob.com.ComFailException: Can't find moniker

I passed  `C:\Windows\System32\CMBEdit.dll  Still not feasible`

Answer (score 0):

**Update:**

This is Jacob question, since the exception is:

```
Exception in thread "main" com.jacob.com.ComFailException: Can't find moniker
    at com.jacob.com.Dispatch.createInstanceNative(Native Method)
    at com.jacob.com.Dispatch.<init>(Dispatch.java:99)
    at com.jacob.activeX.ActiveXComponent.<init>(ActiveXComponent.java:58)
    at test.test.JacobTest.main(JacobTest.java:24)
```

As hinted in another [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2907628/184201):

> COM objects have to be registered to be found. It does not matter in
>   which folder they reside.
>
> Call
>
> ```
> regsvr32 mycomdll.dll
> ```
>
> on the dll.

Comment: That's what I did, but it didn't help